# There is any way to I can extend the ringing time to 2 or any custom input on iOS devices

Tags: ios, react-native, voip

I need to extend the ringing time to 2 or any custom input on iOS devices for VOIP app, so any suggestion for how I can achieve that?

I am using https://github.com/ajith-ab/react-native-voip-call this npm package for VOIP service. right now I need to extend the ringing time to 2 or any custom input on iOS devices so any suggestion for how I can achieve that?